# SQL: Can I get an alias in a GROUP BY query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT date, sum(money) as total
    FROM gasto 
    GROUP BY date;
```

The table in question has two fields: date (where the input is a specific day), and money (an integer).

To print out the sums, for each day, I do this:

```
$resultado=mysqli_query($conectar,$consulta); //this is to get the result
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' - '.$value['total'].'<br>';
```

This results in:

0 - 20

1 - 45

2 - 12

etc.

**My question is, how do I print out each date right before the aumont?**

Comment: Is ```$value['date']``` not working?

Comment: Why I do get minus votes on my question? I would like to know!
Is because it's an easy question? And why my last comment was deleted without further explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$resultado=mysqli_query($conectar,$consulta); //this is to get the result
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' - '. $value['date'] . ' : ' . $value['total'].'<br>';    
}
```

Your selected table names will not change with group by.

You also can do this if you want to give an alias:

```
//SELECT date as mydate, sum(money) as total FROM gasto GROUP BY date;
$resultado=mysqli_query($conectar,$consulta); //this is to get the result
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' - '. $value['mydate'] . ' : ' . $value['total'].'<br>';    
}
```

For the future you can do `print_r($resultado)` to see, what you get from your database fetch method.

Answer (score 0):

Just do **print_r($resultado);** and check the output.
This will help you to understand how you are getting the result.

And the solution to above problem is

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conectar,$consulta); //this is to get the result
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' - '. $value['date'] . ' : ' . $value['total'].'<br>';    
}
```